# React Native setState not updating - called twice in a function. Wait's until finished to update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm, react-native-listview

So I am using React native and Realm. Basically I want to show an indicator before a Realm query starts and then hide it when it's finished. But the indicator doesn't seem to show up. My understandings of React native are still new!

Here is what I have so far:

```
  <SegmentedControlIOS 
    values={['Matched', 'Last Active', 'Distance', 'Age']}
    momentary={false}
    tintColor={'#DB4C2C'}
    style={{
      width: width,
      marginTop: 10
    }}
    selectedIndex={this.state.scIndex}
    onValueChange={(value) => {}}
    onChange={(event) => {
      console.log("CHANGE")
      var selectedIndex = event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex;

      this.sortMatches(selectedIndex)
      this.setState({
        scIndex: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex
      })
    }}/>


  sortMatches(index) {
    this.setState({loading: true})

    var sortMatches = null;

    if (index == 0) {
      sortedMatches = this._sort_matched()
    } else if (index == 1) {
      sortedMatches = this._sort_last_active()
    } else if (index == 3) {
      sortedMatches = this._sort_birthdate()
    }

    let dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(sortedMatches)
    this.setState({dataSource: dataSource, loading: false})
  }

  <ActivityIndicator
    animating={this.state.loading}
    style={[styles.centering, {height: 30, paddingTop: 20}]}
    size="small"/>
```

Comment: do the correct matches appear?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of setState is described in the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate). Quoting from the documentation:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
>   and calls may be batched for performance gains.

In your example, the pending state transition via setState has run a bit later.

Comment: Ya, is there a way I could re order my code to have it render at the start and then again after?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is FIRST setState `loading: true` and THEN call `this.sortMatches(selectedIndex)` in `onChange`. `setState` accepts a callback, like this:

```
onChange={(event) => {
    console.log("CHANGE")
    var selectedIndex = event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex;

    this.setState({
        loading: true,
        scIndex: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex
    }, this.sortMatches(selectedIndex))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set your activity indicator in componentDidMount. Then after you fetched your data stop it. Almost similar as in the documentation [ActivityIndicator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html)